# jQuery ui menu not positioning correctly

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Here's my jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/jgreen/K6QSd/2/

The menu doesn't seem to be respecting my positioning.

```
.menu({
    position: {
        my: "right top",
        at: "right bottom",
        of: $('#button1'),
        collision: "none"
    }
})
```

I'm trying to get the menu to line up with the right side of the button, not the left side that it's currently doing.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: snowp provided a way to get the behavior with css, but I'm really looking for why it's not working with jquery ui.

Edit #2: I did not fully grok a critical part of the documentation. The position option 'Identifies the position of **submenus**...'.  submenu != menu. Doh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jgreen Jquery Solution for your required menu

```
 $(this).next().show().menu().position({

            my: "right top",
            at: "right bottom",
            of: $('#button1'),
            collision: "none" 
})
```

Comment: @j08691 i added jquery solution please check it

Comment: Thanks @snowp. Interesting that the position option didn't work but the ui method that it's suppose to emulate does.

Answer (score 1):

add the following css
  For Menu like this  [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WwkP.jpg)

```
  #subMenu
    {
        float:right; top:0px;right:-80px;
        z-index:1;
    }
```

(Or)

add the following css
    For Menu like this  [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erFR3.jpg)

```
#subMenu
{
   float:right; top:32px;right:40px;
}
```

Comment: "I'm trying to get the menu to line up with the right side of the button, not the left side that it's currently doing.". Your solution merely moves the content within the menu.

Comment: Like @j08691 said, I'm not trying to move the content within the menu to the right. I'm trying the get the menu (with its current size) to line up with the right of the button.

Comment: @j08691 i changed my answer please check it

Comment: @snowp Thanks for your response. I've upvoted your answer because the second one did get the behavior I wanted (with some slightly different values for your top and right), but not marked it as 'the' answer because it's more of a css hack to the problem of jquery ui (I've edited my answer to make it more clear that I'm looking for a jquery ui solution).

Comment: @j08691 i added jquery solution please check it